# How to keep pets from teleporting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a small parrot room, with a glass top. The point is for the parrots to act normal, and for players to view them from the top. The only way for the stubborn parrots to cooperate was to make them my pets, and put them in there. **BUT,** (because there always are problems) the parrots won't stop teleporting to me when I walk away. I could make them sit, but that would defeat the purpose of a free-range type thing... Does anyone know of a command or something that will stop the teleporting without mods?

Comment: If you have access to commands, why not just [summon untamed parrots](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/summon_parrot.php) inside the room?  Then they wouldn't follow you?

Comment: Gah! I'm so dumb. Good point! But now that they are there, any answers would be welcomed, as this is still a problem in other circumstances...

Answer (score 1):

You can put a leash on untamed parrots and transport them into the cage that way. If you're really careful, you can even fly with an elytra while having them dangling behind you.

Xisuma did this in a Hermitcraft episode, but that's hard to find, so I'll link you a flying sheep video instead:

Comment: Yeah, but my parrots are already _in_ there. Is there a way to keep any animals from teleporting? Not just for the parrots, but it would be good to know in other circumstances as well...

Comment: Sorry I'm soooo late to respond... I forgot I had this question XD

Comment: Yes, just make them not tamed. Or, if you have access to commands, just change the owner ID to "12345" or something else.

Comment: You can do that? How? I'm not very good at ID commands. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Search for "entitydata" on the wiki and for "chunk format" for the data structure.